# Python. Проверка значения на наличие в словаре

Tags: python, словари, словарь

Всем привет, с праздниками! Возникла проблема из словарями в Python.
Читал разную документацию и форумы, знаю что можно сделать через key поиск, но не могу понять, как нужно вывести названия. Последняя попытка была через цикл for. Задание:

Есть 10 стран с названиями и общей информации о них ( площадь, население и части мира). Написать Программу для поиска стран, которые находятся в Африке или Азии. Вывод должен быть из их названий.

```
countries={ 
'Нігерія':{'cw': 'Нігерія','sq': '923768','sq':'195900000','ct':'Африка' },
'Німеччина':{'cw': 'Німеччина','sq': '357578','sq':'83000000','ct':'Європа'},
'Пакистан':{'cw': 'Пакистан','sq': '803950','sq':'187300000','ct':'Азія'},
'Італія':{'cw': 'Італія','sq': '301000','sq':'60600000','ct':'Європа'},
'Узбекистан':{'cw': 'Узбекистан','sq': '447400','sq':'31100500','ct':'Азія'},
'Франція':{'cw': 'Франція','sq': '643801','sq':'66990000','ct':'Європа'},
'Палестина':{'cw': 'Палестина','sq': '6220','sq':'5159000','ct':'Азія'},
'Ніґер':{'cw': 'Ніґер','sq': '1267000','sq':'22400000','ct':'Африка'},
'Україна':{'cw': 'Україна','sq': '603628','sq':'41980000','ct':'Європа'},
'Греція':{'cw': 'Греція','sq': '131957','sq':'10760000','ct':'Європа'}
            }

for country in countries:
    if 'Африка' or "Азія" in country:
        print(country)
    else:
        print("-")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
for country in countries:
    if 'Африка' == countries[country]['ct'] or "Азія" == countries[country]['ct']:
        print(country)
#    else:
#        print("-")
```

Answer (score 3):

Более аккуратно, без дублирующейся индексации и в одно условие:

```
for name, data in countries.items():
    if data['ct'] in ('Африка', 'Азiя'):
        print(name)
```